# I am trying to connect my Aiven database to python using the SQLalchemy module

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, aiven

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

db_connection_str = "mysql+pymysql://user:pass@some_mariadb/dbname?charset=utf8mb4"
#Don't worry while running the code , I had replaced all the values in the db_connection_str with my values

engine = create_engine(
    db_connection_str,
    connect_args={
        # "ssl": {
        #     "ssl_ca": "/etc/ssl/cert.pem",
        # }
        # "ssl": {
        #     "ca": "/home/gord/client-ssl/ca.pem",
        #     "cert": "/home/gord/client-ssl/client-cert.pem",
        #     "key": "/home/gord/client-ssl/client-key.pem"
        # }
        # I tried both of these methods and even without using connect_args but it still gives me an error
    })

with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text("select * from jobs"))
    print(result.all())
```

## **This is my entire code, When I try running it while the ssl_ca is uncommented or when I have not entered the connect_args dictionary itself, this is the error I get:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 644, in connect
    sock = socket.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\socket.py", line 851, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\socket.py", line 836, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3304, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 449, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1263, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 712, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 179, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 177, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 390, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 674, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 900, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 896, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 643, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 617, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 358, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 711, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'jovian-careers-db-jovian-careers.a.aivencloud.com' (timed out)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Gunkar\Coding\Self\Flask\Jovian-Careers-Website-V2\database.py", line 20, in <module>
    with engine.connect() as conn:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3280, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 148, in __init__
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2444, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3304, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 449, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1263, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 712, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 179, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 177, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 390, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 674, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 900, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 896, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 643, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 617, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 358, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 711, in connect
    raise exc
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'jovian-careers-db-jovian-careers.a.aivencloud.com' (timed out)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

## **And if I dont uncomment the ssl_ca thing and instead use the other method , then it just says this :

## **

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Gunkar\Coding\Self\Flask\Jovian-Careers-Website-V2\database.py", line 20, in <module>
    with engine.connect() as conn:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3280, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3304, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 449, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1263, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 712, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 179, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 177, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 390, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 674, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 900, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 896, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 643, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 617, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 289, in __init__
    self.ctx = self._create_ssl_ctx(ssl)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ravin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 373, in _create_ssl_ctx
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=ca, capath=capath)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\ssl.py", line 770, in create_default_context
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath, cadata)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**I have mentioned whatever I tried above and what I was expecting is to get the information from one of my tables "jobs" but python didnt even reach that line.**

Also this is the tutorial I am following : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBDHkveJUf4&list=PLiAbjvVKX4Q-7ygi3CYBd8QOES3A3lyqd&index=2&t=8184s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org"

start watching from 2:45:00

**He found his solution to this same problem as he was using another service for his web database called "PlanetScale", I did not use that because I found out it is paid now and the free service is no longer available.**

Also later I am going to integrate this in my flask website as per the tutorial

Comment: You need to have the right set of parameters to connect to a database. It is not clear to us - and apparently to you either - if you need an ssl connection. I suggest you find out that first. If you do need one, then you have to provide the correct path to the certificate, which we cannot help you with, since we do not know where you store your certificates.

Comment: Hi shadow, Can you explain what a ssl certificate is ? The tutorial I am following has no such mention of it, he just simply copies some code from a documentation which mentions something related to ssl and his code starts working. But as I am working with a different website that provides with me with an online SQL databse (aiven) and its not working because they dont have such documentation. Do I need to somehow download this certificate and should I share my control panel of Aiven with you ?

Comment: You need to ask your provider for their connectiin details, we cannot possibly know their requirements. If the provider's documentation does not mention certificates, then most likely they do not require one, but better confirm it with them.

Comment: Do not ever share the contents of a certificate!

Comment: Sorry, I didnt know that, please share the answer